# Session variables lost after redirect - PHP 7.3

Tags: php, variables, session, redirect

I am trying to forward session variables from page1.php to page2.php.
Session variables lost after redirect.
In PHP version 5.3.28 it was working properly. The problem started occuring after upgrade to PHP ver. 7.3.9.

page1.php

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['myvar']=1;
session_write_close();
header( 'Location: page2.php' );
exit();
```

page2.php

```
    session_start();
            echo $_SESSION['myvar'];
            if ( isset($_SESSION['myvar']) && $_SESSION['myvar'] == 1 ){
echo "OK";
unset($_SESSION['myvar']);}
```

Comment: `session_write_close` — Write session data and end session ~ surely that answers your question?

Comment: @RamRaider no, I don’t think it does. _Ending_ the session just means it can not be written to any more in the current script instance, and the data gets written into the session storage. This doesn’t have anything to do with permanently “killing” / deleting / removing the session, it just does what PHP normally would do when the script ends, at an earlier point.

Comment: I've tested your script with PHP 7.3.1 and it works as expected. What is the output of `page2.php`?

Comment: Just get rid of `session_write_close` I do this all the time without using that function and it works perfectly fine

Comment: I removed session_write_close, still the same issue.

Comment: What error you receive? I think you php.ini something wrong.

Comment: Where I can find version 7.3.1 for download?

Comment: I am not getting any error. Just variables are not showing. Yes, I think that it is a problem with php.ini but I don't know what I should check.

Comment: you can copy content of tag [Session] and post here

Comment: `[Session]

session.save_handler = files

session.use_strict_mode = 0

session.use_cookies = 1

session.use_only_cookies = 1

session.name = PHPSESSID

session.auto_start = 0

session.cookie_lifetime = 0

session.cookie_path = /

session.cookie_domain =

session.cookie_httponly =

session.cookie_samesite =

session.serialize_handler = php

session.gc_probability = 1

session.gc_divisor = 1000

session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440

session.referer_check =

session.cache_limiter = nocache

session.cache_expire = 180`

Comment: session.use_trans_sid = 0

session.sid_length = 26

session.trans_sid_tags = "a=href,area=href,frame=src,form="

session.sid_bits_per_character = 5
session.save_path = "C:\Windows\Temp\"

Comment: The same happened to me after upgrading to php 7.3 from 7.1 Still tring to work it out, every session data is lost from one page to another and it worked fine before.

Comment: For this moment I downgraded to PHP 5.3.28. I didn't found better solution so far.